# Enabling table plugin feature on CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem, wcm

I am working with a task right now which I need to display the existing features of a "table" plugin. However, I am having a hard time enabling it. When using this code below, I only get to have the table properties feature. That's the only displayed tool/icon I have on my richtext editor. Can somebody help me enable/display other features/icons such as (insertcolumn, insertrow, etc)?

```
                <tableField jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="richtext">
                    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <table jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*" />
                    </rtePlugins>
                </tableField>
```

I have tried doing this (below) but I still failed.

```
                <tableField jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="richtext">
                    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <table jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="[insertcolumn,insertrow]" />
                    </rtePlugins>
                </tableField>
```

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

That's the only toolbar button that the table plugin provides. To use the other features, right-click on the table itself:

[image: table context menu]

Comment: official site: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/wcm/using_rich_text_editor.html#Tables hope this helps